# regex to match exactly 16 consecutive digits in a potentially larger string

Tags: regex, pcre

I need a regular expression that will match exactly 16 consecutive digits, no more or less, regardless of what, if anything, is surrounding it.  I've gone through a couple iterations but all have had issues:

1. `\d{16}` will match any 16 consecutive digits, including 16 digits within a longer string of digits
2. `^\d{16}$` will match a line that is exactly 16 consecutive digits, but if there is anything else in the string, the match will fail
3. `\D\d{16}\D` will match a string of 16 consecutive digits, but only if it is surrounded by non-digit characters. If the string of 16 digits is alone on the line, it fails
4. `\D?\d{16}\D?` will match a longer string of consecutive digits
5. `[\D^]\d{16}[\D$]` does not treat `^` and `$` as their special meanings, but rather treats them as literal characters.

How can I create the regex I need?

Edit: These are PCRE regex

Comment: Which language you're working with ?

Comment: PCRE style regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookaround

```
(?<!\d)\d{16}(?!\d)
```

- `(?<!\d)` - Match should not be preceded by digit
- `\d{16}` - Match digits (0 - 9) 16 times
- `(?!\d)` - Match should not be followed by digit

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/JPc3mh/1)

Comment: how to mask the middle 6 digits only ?
for eg:
4415554512652337 to
441555******2337

Answer (score 3):

This is close `D\d{16}\D` to what you want, except, as you noted, it grabs the non-digits surrounding the 16-digit sequence. Modify it with [a lookbehind and a lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to use non-digits as anchors, without including them in a match:

```
(?<!\d)\d{16}(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=\D|^)\d{16}(?=\D|$)`

The key here is positive lookarounds. These can verify nondigit characters without capturing them.

- `(?<=\D|^)` Ensure that behind the match is either a nondigit character or the start of the string
- `\d{16}` Capture exactly 16 digits
- `(?=\D|$)` Ensure that following the match is either a nondigit character or the end of the string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5TyCi1/1/)